# Returning Data From from a Sub-query With fetchcolumn()

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

I am trying to simply my code. I know this works and will return a value for $waiver_cash:

```
    $waiver_query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cap_number + waiver_number - :salary - 
                        (SELECT sum(current_salary)
                            FROM salaries
                            WHERE gm = :gm AND franchise IS NULL AND waiver_bid IS NULL) - 
                        (SELECT COALESCE(sum(waiver_bid), 0) FROM salaries
                            WHERE gm = :gm) AS waiver_cash
                      FROM base_numbers;");
$waiver_query->execute(['salary' => $salary, 'gm' => $gm]);
foreach ($waiver_query as $row) {
    $waiver_cash = $row['waiver_cash'];
}
```

However, what I want to do, is this:

```
    $waiver_query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cap_number + waiver_number - :salary_retained - 
                                      (SELECT sum(current_salary)
                                       FROM salaries
                                       WHERE gm = :gm AND franchise IS NULL AND waiver_bid IS NULL) - 
                                         (SELECT COALESCE(sum(waiver_bid), 0) 
                                          FROM salaries
                                          WHERE gm = :gm) AS waiver_cash
                               FROM base_numbers;");
$waiver_query->execute(['salary_retained' => $salary_retained, 'gm' => $gm]);
$waiver_cash = $waiver_query->fetchColumn();
```

When I do it with "fetchColumn()" nothing gets returned. Other than changing the $pdo->prepare to $pdo->query and putting the variables in the SELECT statements, is what I want to do, possible?

Comment: are you sure that your query even returns data? try it in mysql terminal please

Comment: If I run the query in pgadmin, one column of data is returned for "waiver_cash".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I have another query which fetches the data for $salary_retained.

```
    $salary_retained_query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COALESCE(sum(current_salary), 0) FROM salaries WHERE salary_retained= :gm;");
$salary_retained_query->execute(['gm' => $gm]);
$salary_retained = $salary_retained_query->fetchColumn();
```

Some of the GMs didn't have any criteria which matched and so the value returned was "null". Then in the query which I was having issues, the sum was returning a null, so in my webpage, it would return blank. By changing my code from `sum(current_salary` to `COALESCE(sum(current_salary), 0)`, the issue was resolved.

When testing in PGAdmin, those GMs who I knew din't have any value in the "salary_retained" column, I would put a 0 for them in the calculations, so my query worked. Thanks to [islemdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20055884/islemdev) for making me rethink how the data I was using was being returned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).